# Move huge amount of files with directory creating

Tags: scripts

There is src directory with sub-dirs as

```
/tmp/part1
/tmp/part2
/tmp/part3
```

Sub dirs contains huge amount of wav-files

I need to move wav-files to /dst directory so that subdir1,subdir2,etc would be created in
/dst and file moved to neccessary sub-dir in dst directory.

Because of huge amount i do:

```
$source="/tmp"
$dst= "/dst"

find $source -name "*.wav" -exec mv  {} $dst \;
```

But all files are moved to /dst , not by subdir. Is it possible to create subdirs "on-the-fly" ?

Comment: I do not understand why you’re not using `cp -R` for this …

Comment: Because i need to delete files in src path. But it neccessary  to be sure, that files are copied succesfully

Comment: I would use `rsync`, which is very reliable and can also exclude files (sets of files) with the option `--exclude`. You can use the 'archive' option `-a`. But it copies, does not move, so you should delete files from the original location (*but first* make sure that the copying was successful).